# Downloading aws cloudshell file to local windows machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudshell

I tried to download cloudshell file to windows machine. But error showing 'Unable to download the file. Check the file name and path and try again.'. What is the right path I have to provide? Can someone help me with this?